# LINQ method using Where, Contains and Foreach to update Entity.DbSet using a List<T>

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I use Entity Framework to generate the Database table class:

```
public partial class TPTM605
{
    public string EMP { get; set; }
    public string ATTD_DATE { get; set; }
    public string ATTD_TIME { get; set; }
    public string MAC_NO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> GPS_LATI { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> GPS_LONG { get; set; }
    public string APRO_EMP { get; set; }
    public string APRO_DATE { get; set; }
    public string APRO_YN { get; set; }
    public string PROC_DATE { get; set; }
    public string ERR_CODE { get; set; }
    public string KN_DATE { get; set; }
}
```

---

Then I create another class:

```
public class AproData
{
    // Employee ID
    public string emp { get; set; }

    // Attendance Date
    public string attd_date { get; set; }

    /// Attendance time
    public string attd_time { get; set; } 

    // Approve (Y/N)
    public string apro_yn { get; set; }
}
```

---

In the TPTM605 Class, its properties(EMP, ATTD_DATE, ATTD_TIME) is primary key, and default Value of property(APRO_YN) is null.
Then I create a WCF method-SetAproMissCard(string apro_emp, string apro_date, List Data), the input parameter(List Data) is a List of final result of leader approved Yes/No.

I want to use AproData(ID, date, time) to find the record in DbSet, 
then to update the property(APRO_YN) of TPTM605 using AproData(apro_yn).

```
public bool SetAproMissCard(string apro_emp, string apro_date, List<AproData> Data)
{
    bool rst = false;
    try
    {
        using (OracleEmpAppModelEntities oEAME = new OracleEmpAppModelEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in Data)
            {
                oEAME.TPTM605.Where(t => t.EMP.Equals(item.emp) && t.ATTD_DATE.Equals(item.attd_date) && t.ATTD_TIME.Equals(item.attd_time))
                        .ToList().ForEach(t => { t.APRO_EMP = apro_emp; t.APRO_DATE = apro_date; t.APRO_YN = item.apro_yn; });
            }
            oEAME.SaveChanges();
        }
        rst = true;
    }
```

It works fine. But the C# foreach-loop syntax doesn't look smart enough.

### I want to improve it using LINQ extension methods(.Where, .Contains, .ForEach(), etc..) and Lambdas instead of using C# "foreach" syntax. Could Anybody teach me how to implement it? thanks a lot.

p.s. Sorry, my English is poor.. Hope you understand my question..

Comment: Hi @Leo. If you have an exception, why don't you post it here?

Comment: Hi @Boris, the exception is "unable to build  'WcfServiceCsbcEmpApp.Models.AproData' 。the context only support basic type or IEnumerable type。". sorry, that exception message is traditional Chinese. I try to translation it. thx.

Comment: Try making it an object : public bool SetAproMissCard(string apro_emp, string apro_date, object Data)

Comment: Hi, @jdweng, in actual, I want to find a set of LINQ methods(eg. Where, Contains, ForEach, etc.) instead of using C# foreach -loop  originally. thank you.

Comment: I know it's nit picky, but `ForEach` is *not* Linq. It's a normal method of `List<T>`. The Q in Linq stands for *query* and `ForEach` is used to take action, not to query.

Comment: Why not use a JOIN to eliminate the Foreach loop?

Comment: Hi, @mvoigt. Sorry, I didn't fully express what I mean. I already updated my post, thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hi, @jdweng. It is bad that I forget to use Join Instruction. I am not smart in SQL. Thank your comment. There is a Join method in LINQ method. Can I using LINQ Join method to implement it, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
var results = (from item in Data
               join t in oEAME.TPTM605 on  item.emp  equals t.EMP
               where t.ATTD_DATE.Equals(item.attd_date) && t.ATTD_TIME.Equals(item.attd_time)
               select new { APRO_EMP = apro_emp, APRO_DATE = apro_date, APRO_YN = item.apro_yn }).ToList();
```

Comment: Hi, @jdweng, Could you transform your code into LINQ Method Lambda?
Forgive me so picky. Microsoft suggest programers to use LINQ method better than LINQ, and I also prefer to use Lambda(I feel it is a kind art of programing design. HA..)

Comment: I only do joins this way.  Everything else I use Linq.